# How to interpret conditional probability from complex questions?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I came across the following conditional probability questions. According to my comprehension, the question is asking only the probability concerning that yellow candy came from the old bag. However, some of my colleagues are arguing that we need to calculate the probability of both; yellow and green.

[image]

However, this is what I think the correct answer is, am I correct?:

[image]

Comment: Not following.  The two events you must consider are "yellow from bag $1$, green from bag $2$" and "green from bag $1$, yellow from bag $2$".  So the green selection clearly does matter.  If one bag had no greens at all, the solution would be obvious.  For example.

Comment: @lulu I think you are correct, my initial perception was maybe the green one is just to confuse and has nothing to do with calculating the yellow.

Comment: @lulu so if I am correct, using your approach, the end result is 77%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are finding conditional probability, you need to first check the given condition. The given condition is that you have drawn one candie each from the old and the new bag and one of the candies is yellow and one of the candies is green. Now there are two possibilities - $i)$ the yellow candie came from the old bag and the green candie came from the new bag $ii)$ the yellow candie came from the new bag and the green candie came from the old bag.

As per the question, you need to find the conditional probability that the yellow candie came from the old bag (and that the green candie came from the new bag). So it should be,

$ \small P(\text {yellow from old bag}| \text{one green and one yellow}) = \dfrac{P(A)}{P(A) + P(B)}$

where,

$ \small P(A) = P(\text{yellow from old bag}) \cdot P(\text{ green from new bag})$

$ \small P(B) = P(\text{green from old bag}) \cdot P(\text{ yellow from new bag})$

Comment: just to be sure, does the end results using your method comes out to be 77%?

Comment: $P(A) = \frac {20}{100} \cdot \frac {20}{100} = \frac 1 {25}$ and $P(B) = \frac {10} {100} \cdot \frac{14}{100} = \frac 7 {500}$. The answer comes to $\frac{20}{27} \approx 74\%$

Comment: Many thanks for clearing this confusion!